How to get data from yesterday using laravel eloquent
I am using the below code to get data for today in laravel
->whereMonth('dob', Carbon::now()->format('m'))
->whereDay('dob', Carbon::now()->format('d'))
->paginate(10)

But i like to get the data for yesterday, any ideas?

Carbon::yesterday() or you can sub days

Found this answer, the below worked for me..thank you
->whereMonth('dob', Carbon::now()->format('m'))->whereDay('dob', Carbon::yesterday()->format('d'))->paginate(10),


You'll want to do yesterday for the month as well. Otherwise, you're going to get thrown off on the 1st of the month.

->whereMonth('dob', Carbon::yesterday()->format('m'))
->whereDay('dob', Carbon::yesterday()->format('d'))
->paginate(10)

you'll have to do yesterday() for the month and the day
